# Water Droplet permeability through Graphene Oxide

Tags: water, carbon-allotropes

[image: Over simplified question model: Behavior exhibited top or bottom?]

**TL;DR:** The above image is an over simplified model to my question begging to know whether the permeation behavior exhibited by water droplets through graphene oxide is the top image or the bottom.

---

I couldn't find information about this anywhere:

It has been confirmed that water vapor and pools of liquid water can pass through graphene oxide films (prepared for stability in water on aluminium substrates) assuming the interlayer distances and quantity of layers are appropriate for optimal passage.

However, **I do not know whether or not a droplet of water (placed on one side of graphene oxide) will permeate through the graphene oxide film and emerge intact on the other side of the film.** I could simply confirm this by spraying water onto graphene oxide but I cannot make a legitimate film on my own just yet is why I ask. 
Basically, stated differently, I don't want to end up spraying graphene oxide with water droplets on one side and end up with a stream of water on the other side; they are to ideally remain as droplets.

The question is very simple but also very important in determining to what extent G.O. can be utilized. There are also different studies that conclude different permeation mechanisms for water through G.O. so I can't even reason the answer out on my own. Quite maddening.

Thank you all and sorry for the pure info. extraction but it's for the greater good!

EDIT1: Oh, the preferred droplet max diameter would be 100 micrometers.

**EDIT2: *Thanks for the reads; I'll try and find the best method for making graphene alumina oxide to try and find the answer on my own. If anyone can point me to the best method meanwhile, that would also be great. Thanks again***

Comment: You may want to clarify the "emerge intact on the other side of the film" part. The situation seems to be VERY dependent on experimental conditions, type of graphene oxide, actual amount of water, etc. GO seems to be an umbrella terms for a diverse set of materials, with different edge structure, oxygen content, holes on the sheet etc.  Also, if a droplet is stable on the surface, why would lay out as a water film? Or the other way, if the surface is wetable, and water spreads out as film, why would you have separate droplets at the first place?

Comment: 1. "Emerge intact on the other side of the film"
---- Hi! By this I'll use an example of water sprayed downward and centered onto a napkin versus onto graphene oxide: 

For the napkin, continued spraying makes the whole napkin wet until eventually water gathers and drips at the center. Individual droplet paths cannot be traced because of the merging.

For graphene oxide, will the same occur, or will each droplet 'emerge intact on the other side of the [graphene oxide] film'?

Comment: 2. "...type of graphene oxide"  
----Stability of Graphene Oxide in water has been attributed to aluminium filters:  
  
"During filtration, the pH value of the graphene oxide solution is typically around 3 to 5. In this range of pH values, AAO corrodes to release Al3+ cations, which were incorporated into the graphene oxide membranes. These trivalent aluminum cations act as crosslinkers, holding the negatively charged graphene oxide sheets together in water."
  
-http://bit.ly/1HExnui

Comment: 3. "if the surface is wetable, and water spreads out as film, why would you have separate droplets at the first place?"  
  
---- Well I don't know whether or not the water spreads out. The primary goal for me is just to know the behavior of water as it passes through graphene oxide. Everyone knows vapor passes as well as pools of water, but what is not explained is the behavior of water droplets passing through G.O.


Thanks for reading this essay~

Comment: (you may want include relevant parts in the question to improve it and help others, instead of answering me the questions)

Comment: My answers to you are just me repeating myself but I've included an image for clarification. Thanks for being the first to actually respond!!!